# Published object not being updated

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, apple-watch, watchos

I'm building a WatchOS companion app. In a View there's a Slider that reads and writes value. This value is being communicated between iOS and WatchOS app.

```
struct ReadingView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var watcher: ViewModelWatch
    var body: some View {
        CompactSlider(value: $watcher.sliderValue, in: -1000...1000, step: 50, direction: .center) {
            VStack {
                Text("Compensation")
                Text(String(format: "%.0fK", watcher.sliderValue))
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: watcher.sliderValue) { newValue in
            ViewModelWatch.shared.session.transferUserInfo(["compensationValue": newValue])
        }
        
    }
}
```

This is how my model looks like:

```
class ViewModelWatch : NSObject, WCSessionDelegate, ObservableObject {

    static let shared = ViewModelWatch()
    var session: WCSession = .default
    @Published var sliderValue = 0.0
    
    init(session: WCSession = .default){
        self.session = session
        super.init()
        self.session.delegate = self
        session.activate()
    }
    
    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
        self.sliderValue = userInfo["compensationValue"] as? Double ?? 0.0        
    }
}
```

Steps and what's happening:

1. Ran the apps on both iOS and WatchOS.
2. Sent "compensationValue" UserInfo from iOS app and received in `didReceiveUserInfo` in the Watch app, the Slider view in iOS app updates just fine.
3. Sent "compensationValue" UserInfo from Watch app and received in `didReceiveUserInfo` in the iOS app, the Slider view in iOS app updates just fine.

Issue:

4. Now when I repeat the 2nd step i.e., send "compensationValue" UserInfo from iOS app to Watch app, the `CompactSlider` doesn't update.

It's like once `@Published var sliderValue = 0.0` is written by `CompactSlider`, it doesn't update views when updated by `didReceiveUserInfo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `private` to this line

```
private init(session: WCSession = .default){
```

It will expose if there is an area in your code where you are not using the same instance.

You should only be using `ViewModelWatch.shared` so they can share information.

Another call of `ViewModelWatch()` will be separate from `ViewModelWatch.shared`

Comment: I'm using `ViewModelWatch` as environmentobject, private protection makes it inaccessible. How come this is gonna help?

Comment: @Codetard it will expose if `ViewModelWatch()` is being used somewhere else in the app. If it is then there are 2 different instances of the `ViewModel` You should only be using `ViewModelWatch.shared`

Comment: @Codetard using the environment object directly would also solve the issue `watcher.session.transferUserInfo(["compensationValue": newValue])`. It doesn't change that the `private` `init` is still best, there is a `Delegate` you don't want to have multiples of those.

Comment: I tried using it directly, didn't help! 

Answer (score 0):

Try to assign value on main queue, like

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveUserInfo userInfo: [String : Any] = [:]) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
       self.sliderValue = userInfo["compensationValue"] as? Double ?? 0.0        
    }
}
```

or make view model `MainActor` if deployment target version allows

```
@MainActor
class ViewModelWatch
```

Comment: Sorry, I've tried this but doesn't work. What else I can try?

Comment: then an issue probably is not in the provided code, I don't see anything wrong with it

Comment: Exactly, spent a few hours myself trying to figure this out, not able to find anything. :/